# How to change numbers in an array to symbols

Tags: c, arrays, function, logical-operators

I am trying to find a good way to convert digits of a string in an array to a # symbol.

I would like to be clear, this is for a homework assignment. I am asking for help because not only am I running into roadblocks that I would like to overcome; but I want to understand the relationship between arrays and functions as well.

I have done some code, shown below, but I feel like I am confusing myself on the relationship between calls in arrays when they are within a function.

Here is what I have done:

```
void coverNumbers(char s[]) {
    char num;

    if (s[num] >= '0' || s[num] <= '9')
        num = '#';
}
```

I feel like I am so close to having a solution.

If I type in `43ll0` within the array, I want the `43ll0` to become `##ll#`.

Thank you for your help everyone, and have a wonderful night!

Comment: `char num;` - then use `num` - `num` has not been given a value

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way. You need to loop over the string to check and replace each character individually.

**Try This**

```
void coverNumbers(char s[]) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            s[i] = '#';
}
```

You have additional logic mistakes. If you have some questions on why I changed a specific thing please ask in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem! But for my understanding, how does that for loop even work. You are looping the array itself?

Comment: A character array is a string. And strings in C end with a null character (\0). So this for loop keeps going until s[i] is null, which is the same as writing s[i] != '\0'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *covernumbers* receives a C string, ie a pointer to a `char` array terminated by a null byte `'\0'`, you should just iterate on all characters and perform the modification.  Note however that you used `||` instead of `&&` to test for digits. `s[num]` is a digit if it is `>= '0'` **and** `<= '9'`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
void coverNumbers(char s[]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            s[i] = '#';
    }
}
```

You can also use the pointer and increment it. `void coverNumbers(char s[])` and `void coverNumbers(char *s)` are equivalent and the second version make it more obvious that `s` is a pointer, not an actual array.

```c
void coverNumbers(char *s) {
    while (*s) {
        if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
            *s = '#';
        s++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You should not use stack overflow for such kind of problems. But you can always ask questions on the issues you are facing, if the similar question is not already been asked by others.

**SOLUTION:**

**Algorithm:**

- Get the length of the string
- Iterate each character in the string
- Based on the value in current position (index) of string, replace with '#' if it's a digit.
- Print the output

**Code:**

```
void coverNumbers(char s[]) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') 
            s[i] = '#';
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: Note: You need to add "#include <string.h>" to your file to use this code

Comment: @IssamRafihi Thanks. But this online gdb compiler did not ask me to add it. **https://www.onlinegdb.com/**.